# Good OpenID Selector for DotNetNuke

Tags: .net, openid, dotnetnuke

As you know DNN has OpenID support built into the system, I'm about to build my own openID selector so people don't have to remember the URLs. But before hacking I just want to know if there's an easier solution or a standing module for DNN that will do the openID selecting buttons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DotNetNuke ships with an openid provider, though it's been a while since it was updated. To install it go to host->extensions and click the install available extensions list. Alternatively it can be downloaded at http://dnnauthopenid.codeplex.com/ . Note: the source is within the resources.zip, DotNetNuke automatically unpacks it after installation.

Comment: does it have an openid selector? I have already enabled the openid provider in DNN, but there's no selector in that the user needs to know the URL to google, yahoo, etc.

Comment: I agreee if the core one had a selector it would be awsome - might try with the codeplex one and add the selector to it - same some work at least

Answer (score 1):

Is there an OpenID connector still available in DNN9? The one referred in this thread doesn't seem to work with DNN9.